# how to run a faceapi query on images stored in Azure blobs?

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I have some images in azure container as blobs, I wanted to detect if there are any faces in the images using faceapi and create a Person Group with different persons in python. I do not want to download images into local directory. Using the following code I was able to run read an image from a blob but the faceapi is not accepting that as input.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

blob = BlobClient(account_url="https://****.blob.core.windows.net/",
       container_name="demo",credential="**" )

data = blob.download_blob()
```

Let me know if there is a way I will be able to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the code you provide, when you create a `BlobClient`, you do not provide blobName. Please update the code as `BlobClient(account_url="", container_name="", blob_name="",  credential="account key")`

For example

```
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face import FaceClient
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face.models import TrainingStatusType, Person
import os
import io
import json
import uuid
import time
import sys
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient
account_key = ''
blob = BlobClient(account_url="https://*.blob.core.windows.net/",
                  container_name="image",
                  blob_name='my.jpg',
                  credential=account_key)
image = blob.download_blob()
endpoint = 'https://*.cognitiveservices.azure.com/'
key = ''
face_client = FaceClient(endpoint, CognitiveServicesCredentials(key))
PERSON_GROUP_ID = str(uuid.uuid4())
face_client.person_group.create(
    person_group_id=PERSON_GROUP_ID, name=PERSON_GROUP_ID)
woman = face_client.person_group_person.create(PERSON_GROUP_ID, "Woman")
face_client.person_group_person.add_face_from_stream(
    PERSON_GROUP_ID, woman.person_id, io.BytesIO(image.content_as_bytes(max_concurrency=3)))
face_client.person_group.train(PERSON_GROUP_ID)
while (True):
    training_status = face_client.person_group.get_training_status(
        PERSON_GROUP_ID)
    print("Training status: {}.".format(training_status.status))
    print()
    if (training_status.status is TrainingStatusType.succeeded):
        break
    elif (training_status.status is TrainingStatusType.failed):
        sys.exit('Training the person group has failed.')
    time.sleep(5)
```

[image]